# Function returns multiple variables

Tags: javascript

I have this if else script. It is currently returning an image to variable R if the function is true. I need it to ALSO return a numerical result as well as the image. So R2 = 1 if true, 0 if false. I'm not sure how to set this up.

```
    Question: what is 50% + 50%?

<input type="text" length="3" id="ANSWER1B">

<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Q1B()">

<!--QUESTION 1B-->
<script>// <![CDATA[
    function Q1B()
    {
        var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1B").value;
        var A;
        if (A == '100%') {
        R = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png"/>';
    } else {
        R = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png"/>'
    } 
document.getElementById("RETURN1B").innerHTML = R;
    }
// ]]></script>

<p id="RETURN1B">
```

I've found other posts on this subject but I don't understand the answers very well. My coding level is pretty much day 1. Please help.

Comment: In your code there aren't nothing about returning values. You are assigning a string value to `R` variable, but no more. I don't understand your question and what you are trying to achieve. Please, explain better

Comment: What you want to do with R2?, you wanna display that any where?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to display it anywhere. I need the picture and a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take two seperate variables and replace them in different div's seperately.

```js
function Q1B()
    {
        var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1B").value;
        var number;
        if (A == '100%') {
        R = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png"/>';
        number = 1;
    } else {
        R = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png"/>'
        number = 0;
    } 
document.getElementById("RETURN1B").innerHTML = R;
document.getElementById("Number").innerHTML =  number;
    }
```

```html
Question: what is 50% + 50%?

<input type="text" length="3" id="ANSWER1B">

<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Q1B()">

<p id="RETURN1B">
<p id="Number">
```

Comment: Gold. Thank you so much.

Comment: No mentions, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

***You can use that function for returning multiple value***

public int Multiple returns(int m, int n, ref int max) 
{

if (m < n)

{

enter code here
    max=m;
    return n;
 }
  else
 {

```
max=n;  
return m;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

You should make `R` an object.  You can then have an `R1` value which is the picture, and an `R2` value which is numeric (though it would be better to name them more descriptively).  You can then return `R` at the end of your function.

```
function Q1B()
{
    var A = document.getElementById("ANSWER1B").value;
    var R = {};
    if (A == '100%') {
        R.R1 = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rock-hand.png"/>';
        R.R2 = 1;
    } else {
        R.R1 = '<img src="http://leowestonvfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thumbs-down.png"/>';
        R.R2 = 0;
    } 
    return R;
}
```

Comment: How do I then get these as 2 separate values? See edited question. I wish to use  <p id="RETURN1B"> in one place to see the image, and then have the number 0 or 1 returned somewhere else.